# printing Random Unicode Characters in java through infinite FOR loop

Tags: java, for-loop, unicode, infinite

I want to print random Unicode characters in a JFRAME in java by using an infinite `for loop`.

I am a newbie in java programming and i hope the answer is not too complex.

this is the code so far-

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Matrix extends JFrame{
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_REPS = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a;

        Random rand=new Random();

        for(a=1;a>0;)
        {
            JLabel lbl=new JLabel();
            lbl.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
            lbl.setFont(new Font("MS Arial Unicode",Font.BOLD,12));
            lbl.setText("\\u30"+Integer.toHexString(rand.nextInt(96) + 160));
        }

        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        //error! lbl cannot be resolved to a variable
        frame.getContentPane().add(lbl);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    }  
}
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you provide details on something that you have tried

Comment: General advice for new programmers: Break down your problem into smaller problems and focus on solving each independently.  In this case, you can break it down into two problems: 1. Generate random Unicode characters with a `for` loop.  2. Create a `JFrame` and write text into it.  Then, break down those problems into even smaller problems.  This will help you learn in small steps and ask clear, concise questions.  Good luck!

Comment: i searched for hours but couldn't find the specific answer i was looking for ;i wanted to create a program that would randomly generate and display unicode characters in a jframe using a loop.

Comment: `lbl` goes out of scope at the end of the for-loop.  Rewrite your code so that you can move `frame.getContentPane().add(lbl);` inside the loop.

Comment: how to i repetatively make new jlabels and add random characters in them using a loop?

Answer (score 0):

I used a while loop, they're easier for infinite numbers. As for JFRAME, you're going to want to look at another answer, as I'm not very good with javax.swing.* As of now it just puts it into the console

```
public Random random = new Random();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    while(true) {
        int i = random.nextInt(127);
        System.out.print((char)i);
    }
}
```